# Domination property of expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Suppose both random variables $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative. In particular, $Y$ satisfies $Y\leq c$, a.s., where $c$ is some positive constant. Now I want to formally show that 
\begin{equation}
E((X-EX)Y)=0. 
\end{equation}
.

I tried the following argument Writing $X-EX=Z$,
\begin{align}
E(ZY)=E(Z1_{\{|Z|\geq 0\}}Y)+E(Z1_{\{|Z|<0\}}Y).
\end{align}
Then, since $(Z1_{\{|Z|\geq 0\}}Y)\leq cZ$, it follows that $E(Z1_{\{|Z|\geq 0\}}Y)\leq cEZ=0$ by the domination property of the expectation. Further, because $0\leq (Z1_{\{|Z|\geq 0\}}Y)$, we have $E(Z_{1\{|Z|\geq 0\}}Y)\geq0$. Similarly for the second term.

Any comments/suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Let me guess $X,Y$ are independent?

Comment: Nope I am not necessarily assuming they are independent

Comment: then it is wrong in general.

Comment: I see, could you point me out what's wrong with my proof then?

Comment: Carmichael already gave you a counterexample.

Comment: Yes I understand that. Just wanted to figure out what was wrong with my argument..

Comment: Splitting $|Z| \ge 0$ and $< 0$ makes no sense. I think you meant $Z\ge 0$ and $Z < 0$. Even then you have $Z1_{Z \ge 0} Y \le c|Z| $ whose expected value is not zero in general.

Comment: Ah I got the point. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily true that $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])Y]=0$, even under the stated hypotheses.

For instance, suppose that $X$ takes the values $0$ and $1$, each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, and that $Y=X$. Then
$$\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])Y]=\mathbb{E}[XY]-\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}\neq 0$$